# Cannot access private members from base class using friend classes

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
class Base
{
    friend class SubClass;
    int n;
    virtual int getN()
    {
        return n;
    }
};

class SubClass: public Base
{
public:
    SubClass() {}
    SubClass(const SubClass& s) {}


};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SubClass s;
    int x = s.getN();

    return 0;
}


error C2248: 'Base::getN' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Base'
```

What more do I have to do to access my private members from Base ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `friend` declaration means that `SubClass` gets to access it *in the scope of `SubClass`*.

If you want users of a class to access something, at some point you need to a write `public:` function:

```
class SubClass : public Base
{
public:
    int getN()
    {
        return Base::getN();
    }
};
```

You can write a using declaration to bring a base class function into the current class:

```
class SubClass : public Base
{
public:
    // getN is considered declared at this point now (in public)
    using Base::getN(); 
};
```

Comment: Or `using Base::getN;`, if verbosity isn't your thing.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Oh duh, lemme add that.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just declare `n` as `protected`?

Answer (score 1):

The code in `main` is not trying to access a `SubClass` method, it's trying to access a `Base` method - that's why it doesn't work.

Try adding an override in `SubClass`:

```
virtual int getN()
{
    return Base::getN();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getN()` is never made public, so tmain() can't call it.

Make a sub class a friend of a base class is not the right way to do this anyway. It is a confusing subversion of the type system. If you want to access non-public members of a base class from a sub class but not have them public, make them protected.